# django-storages upload to S3 closes server with no error

Tags: django, django-storage, python-django-storages

I'm using **Django 2.x** and **django-storages** to upload media files to the **S3 Bucket**.

My model is like

```
class Media(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_media_upload_path)
```

The Django settings have

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('S3_STORAGE', 'test-bucket')
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
```

and the environment variable is set for

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=my-key
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=my-secret
```

**When I upload a file from the postman, it closes the server without any error.**

I tried debugging DRF Serializer's save method

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
    log.info('Saving with kwargs: {}'.format(kwargs))
    new = super().save(**kwargs)
    log.info('Saved: {}'.format(new))
    return new
```

It prints the first line, but no output after the `super().save()` line.

Removing `django-storages` configuration from the settings file is working fine and uploading files in the local directory.

> Edit 2: Upload from Django shell

uploading from Django shell with the following command

```
file = File(open('/path/to/file'))
m = Media(user=user, file=file)
m.save()
```

gives error

```
File "/home/scanova/.virtualenvs/qcg-TqOLHEIu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3transfer/upload.py", line 86, in read
   return self._fileobj.read(amount)
File "/home/scanova/.virtualenvs/qcg-TqOLHEIu/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
   (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 10: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Have you tried to upload using django's shell(for debugging purposes)?

Comment: I tried with Django's shell, check **Edit 2**

Comment: Are you trying to create some buckets in runtime if yes then AWS_AUTO_CREATE_BUCKET=True may be the cause of error. Also can you check your IAM policy

Comment: No, a bucket is already there. Files were uploading earlier. It stopped at a sudden.

Comment: @AnujTBE try opening the file with the utf-8 encoding

Comment: @Devit How can I open the file? The upload is handled by `django-storages`.

Comment: The Reason for your `UnicodeDecodeError` when opening with `Django Shell` is that you need to open the file like: `File(open('/path/file.jpg', 'rb'))`.
I am facing the exact same problem. With Django Shell i can save() the file. No error appears, but nothing is stored to S3. Any news here?

Answer (score 0):

After i also struggled with that i finally found it very useful to add `boto3` debbuging logs. In the **Django Shell**, before you execute `m.save()`, please enable `boto3` logs:

```py
import boto3
boto3.set_stream_logger('')
```

This will give you a whole lot of information what **django-storages** tries to do. In my case it concatenated the Buckets for Static & Media files.